# Change text box value of an iframe on a different domain using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, forms, iframe, textbox

I have an Iframe for a page that allows people to sign up for my email newsletters.

I want to auto fill the email field in the iframe based on the querystring url (page.html?email=email)

I know how to do the querystring stuff, I'm just not sure If I'm able to access the input text box within the frame.  The form or the textbox neither have id's they only have names.

I've tried the following..

```
$("email_frame").contents.find('input[name=email]').append("test");
```

Any help would be great.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If an IFRAME is loaded from a different domain than the main page, the 2 **can't** interact using JavaScript or CSS.

Comment: Cross site scripting has been a paramount of the security in the modern browsers.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to do this by passing the data as

```
iframe.src = 'otherdomain/frame.html#bob@foo.com'
```

and using it in the iframe as

```
window.onload = function ()
{
     data = window.location.hash;
}
```

for more details read : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/architecture/bb735305.aspx

Answer (score 0):

One trick that I've used to get around these little issues is sending an anonymous function to setTimeout():

```
var execMe = function() {$("email_frame").contents.find('input[name=email]').append("test");};
var result = setTimeout("execMe", 1000);
```

Disclaimer: I'm not certain this will work in this circumstance, and it **is** hacky.  Use at your own risk.  Just tossing around an idea :)