# how to writing to text box inside an iframe

Tags: javascript, html

I have a `main.html`, inside it is `<ifram id='if' name='if'>`, which loads another site (this loads a site not in my domain, like Facebook).

The site which is loaded in the `iframe` has `<form name='form2' id='form2'>`, and in it there's `<input type='text' name='tb' id='tb'>`

Also in `main.html`, I have a button and I was wondering if we could place some Javascript on the button so that when we click it, the text in textbox named `tb` changes to say 'az'.

How can we do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You can' do that** because that would be cross-site scripting, which is prohibited for security reasons. You could use a proxy, feed the HTML in the `iframe` through your own site so it's no longer cross-site from the browser's perspective.

If the `<iframe>` is from the same domain, the elements are easily accessible as:

```
$("#iFrame").contents().find("#someDiv")
```

Test: http://jsfiddle.net/Yy6tu/ press `Ctrl+Shift+j` and see what you got!

---

**UPDATE:** In case you have the a `other.html` file on your same folder, you can do this:

**main.html**:

```
<head>
    $('document').ready(function(){
        $("#if").contents().find("#b").val('lalalala');
    });
</head>

<body>
    <input type='button' name='executer' value="Maro">
    <iframe width="600" height="400" src='other.html' name='if' id="if"></iframe>
</body>
```

**other.html**:

```
<form action="x" name="form2" id="form2"> 
     <input type="text" name="tb" id="b">
</form>
```

That should work!

Comment: Thanx @Tom Sarduy , so can we get location/source_code of iframe from parent which loads site from different domain :)?

Comment: And @Tom , i cant get your syntax to work.In my example i put $("if").contents().find("tb").value='fd' this in a buttons(in parent) onClick param , but it doesnt works ?

Comment: @AdamSmith: because the `iframe` is loaded from external site (Read carefully the answer)

Comment: And sorry i cant vote up now (will do later:)) as i dont have 15 reputation now :)

Comment: @AdamSmith: In that case your syntax is wrong: use this:  
`$("if").contents().find("#tb").val('#fd')` PD. Don't worry about the upvote ;)

Comment: still not working dude :)
Here's content of main.html :-
'
<iframe src='2.html' name='if' id="if"></iframe><input type='button' name='executer' onClick='$("if").contents().find("#tb").val('#fd')' value="Maro">
'
And heres the content of 2.html :-
'
<form action="" name="form2" id="form2">
<input type="text" name=tb" id="b">
</form>
'

Comment: @AdamSmith: Oh my... you are opening and closing the `iframe` with no content inside. And put the jQuery in `main.html`. Now is a different question, use the search input my friend.

Comment: Hey i couldnt get a word of what you said , can you show the edited part :)
And thanks bro for extending constant support :)

Comment: @AdamSmith: You need to put `</iframe>` after `</form>`

Comment: Now the button is not visible :D
Google Chrome.

Answer (score 1):

That my friend is not possible. Cross-domain protection although limits some features but is of great advantage.

[StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2141535/change-text-box-value-of-an-iframe-on-a-different-domain-using-jquery)

This might help:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb735305.aspx

A possible solution would be to re-load the iframe. And add the text value as a param in iframe's url query string. But that would be a far-fetched solution.

Another possible solution would be to use an intermediary iframe or otherwise known as proxy iframe. This might help:

http://www.tomslabs.com/index.php/2012/06/iframes-and-javascript-cross-domain-security/

**EDIT:**

If iframe is on same domain as page than this should work.

```
$('#if').contents().find('#b').val('fd');
```

Comment: This could also help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/364952/jquery-javascript-accessing-contents-of-an-iframe

Comment: Thanx for your alternative @Jehanzeb.Malik :)
And can how can we get location/source_code of iframe from parent which loads site from different domain :)?

Comment: @AdamSmith Read my lips carefully: Same origin policy.

Comment: @AdamSmith The solution that I was suggesting would only work if both the sites are developed by you. Then you can catch the url query string param and use it accordingly inside iframe. But as you mentioned that you would be opening other sites like facebook (which you dont have control of), this solution won't work. But if you are able to proxy the iframe you can make it work. But I will say only implement it if really necessary.

Comment: If you dont know how to proxy iframe this might help. 
http://www.tomslabs.com/index.php/2012/06/iframes-and-javascript-cross-domain-security/

Comment: Okay let me check the link 
And yeah both site is developed by me & are in same domain,same folder now.

Comment: Well you should have clearly mentioned that you are loading page from same domain. Loading facebook is not loading from same domain. If both pages are on same domain than this should suffice `$('#if').contents().find('#b').val('fd');`

Comment: @DannyBeckett : Okay maybe i should ask updated question as new question :)

Answer (score 0):

This is strictly not possible, since it directly violates [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy).

Comment: Thanx Danny , can we get location/source_code of iframe from parent which loads site from different domain :)?

Comment: @AdamSmith No, same problem with same origin policy.